# Rails 4 Pass Arguments To Sidekiq Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am new to Sidekiq and currently using a worker to send push notifications asynchronously. Push notifications are sent when a message is sent by a user to another.

Since Sidekiq best practices are to make worker params small and simple, is it fine to pass the message text (<140 characters) directly in the params ?

```
perform(message_text, user_id)
```

Or is it better to fetch it with the message_id?

Comment: It is better to get it using the message_id

Comment: Even if you make extra db requests?

Comment: that'd have to be up to your app. If the extra requests cause a bottleneck then you'd be fine sending the message directly. [Don't optimize prematurely](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: You would want to pass preform(message_id, user_id) and inside of the worker you should Message.find_by_id message_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's totally fine if the text is all you need.  Even better might be to include the message_id as another parameter so you can lookup the message if you need to in the future, i.e.

```
perform(message_text, user_id, message_id)
```